# How to consume a RestFull service using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a API using ASP.NET Web API which return a json list and receive as well, on .NET Platform to make a `POST` or `GET` I use something like :

```
private string UrlLocalTest = "http://192.168.0.102:3000/api/";

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostWeb(Model model)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Uri url = new Uri(string.Concat(Url, "gone/POST"));
        return await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GET(string name)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        Uri url = new Uri(string.Concat(UrlLocalTestTwo, "/GET" + name));
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        return response;
    }
```

And to return a token from my WebApi using `oauth2` it goes like :

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Authenticate(string pEmail = null, string pPassword = null)
    {
        var Client = new HttpClient();

            var _tokenArgs = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("username",pEmail),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",pPassword),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","password")
            });
            Uri url = new Uri(UrlLocalTest);
            return await Client.PostAsync(url, _tokenArgs);                   
    }
```

How can I perform those methods and actions using Android ? I found something close to [this](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), but I believe is more complex on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). It provides easy access to HTTP-based services without too much abstraction. Why do you think it will be more complex on Android?

Comment: Thanks I'll check this link, because I came from .NET and there basically the same code on WPF works in Forms, works in UWP and we just need to add a reference and done, but using android, i see is diferent how to dangle things, the language is Java but not all libraries on "ordinary" Java works in Android Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

User volley. It is very easy to use and handle.

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html